# Get an image based on the last character of the name?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 images, named img1.png, img2.png, img3.png .
Is it possible to load them once at a time clicking on the same button, getting the number of their name?

first button click -> read image names -> img**1** is first
second button click -> read image names -> img**2** is second
third button click -> read image names -> img**3** is third

EDIT:
I explain better, I'm just trying to figure out what's the best approach:
the example above would allow me to just create a method and avoid creating an array of images.
Second approach is to create an array.
Third approach, create a counter and load an image based on the counter value.
Other approaches?

Comment: Do you have them in a drawable array?

Comment: Nope, just in drawable folder. EDIT: and I'm trying to do this to see if it's possible to avoid creating an array.

Comment: what exactly you want? Is it fixed that you will have 3 images? Or you want all images to be shown one by one on button click? Like a slideshow? And show what have you tried?

Comment: I can't seem to see the problem here. You know how to load 1 image by clicking a button, right? If not then your question is not clear enough. If yes then instead of loading the image just use an index (could be an `static int` for example) and decide which image should be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable say

```
int nowDisplayNumber=0;
String imageName="img"+ ++nowDisplayNumber+".png";//or other approach for construct the image id, or image name
.....//display your image use imageName here.
```

Please notice that if you do not want the image displayed from the beginning again every time you restart your application, you may need to store the latest image number into a file and read it when application begins

Comment: See? It wasn't hard to understand. Simple and working, thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] imagename = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};


In onClick()

  switch(view.getId) {

     case R.id.button1 :
       button1.setBackgroundResource(imagename[0]);
     break;
     case R.id.button2 :
       button2.setBackgroundResource(imagename[1]);
     break;
     case R.id.button3 :
       button3.setBackgroundResource(imagename[2]);
     break;
  }
```

Comment: No need to create an array if you have 3 different buttons... I said the click must be on the same button. Anyway yes, this is the array approach.